# how to reduce the svg path in web page

Tags: svg

I want to reduce the size of search icon in web page (which is a facelets file). Can anyone suggest how it can be possible.
my current code of jsf is

```html
<div>
  <a href="search.html" class="nav-item toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#advancesearch" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <svg version="1.1" id="_x39_ac692fd-fab4-4127-97e6-094d15a4d3bc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
              <path class="st0" d="M509.9,643.5L354.8,488.4c26.4-28,42.4-65.5,42.4-106.7c0-86.4-70.4-156.7-156.7-156.7S83.7,295.4,83.7,381.7
    s70.4,156.8,156.8,156.8c41.2,0,78.6-16,106.7-41.8l155.1,155.1c1.1,1.1,2.8,1.6,3.9,1.6s2.8-0.5,3.9-1.6
    C512.1,649,512.1,645.7,509.9,643.5z M94.7,381.7c0-80.3,65.5-145.7,145.8-145.7s145.7,65.5,145.7,145.7s-65.5,145.8-145.7,145.8
    C160.1,527.5,94.7,462,94.7,381.7z"></path>
            </svg>
    <p>Advance search</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: PrimeFaces does not know anything about svg and JSF even less. So you need to solve it the svg way for browsers. And tip: please take a new look at your question. It is not formatted correctly, please improve this.

Comment: you can give the svg element a width or you can give the `<a>` parent a width. You may also need to give the `<a>` a `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to select and style the `<svg>` element just as you would any other element in an HTML document.

In this situation you might use the following (attribute) selector:

```
a[href="search.html"] svg {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
a[href="search.html"] svg {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="search.html" class="nav-item toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#advancesearch" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9">
<path d="M509.9,643.5L354.8,488.4c26.4-28,42.4-65.5,42.4-106.7c0-86.4-70.4-156.7-156.7-156.7S83.7,295.4,83.7,381.7 s70.4,156.8,156.8,156.8c41.2,0,78.6-16,106.7-41.8l155.1,155.1c1.1,1.1,2.8,1.6,3.9,1.6s2.8-0.5,3.9-1.6 C512.1,649,512.1,645.7,509.9,643.5z M94.7,381.7c0-80.3,65.5-145.7,145.8-145.7s145.7,65.5,145.7,145.7s-65.5,145.8-145.7,145.8 C160.1,527.5,94.7,462,94.7,381.7z"></path>
</svg>
<p>Advance search</p>
</a>
</div>
```